# Logstash aggregate plugin with task id across multiple line

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to aggregate the events based on a process id. The process id is not in sequence and span across multiple lines. Below is one such sample -

```
2019 Apr 23 14:01:44:870 GMT +0000 BW.EnterpriseFlifoFormatter-EnterpriseFlifoFormatter USER [BW-User] - Interface Name : EFF: Process ID :674526635 Main Process has started^M
2019 Apr 23 14:01:44:870 GMT +0000 BW.EnterpriseFlifoFormatter-EnterpriseFlifoFormatter USER [BW-User] - Interface Name : EFF: Process ID :674526636 Main Process has started^M
2019 Apr 23 14:01:44:878 GMT +0000 BW.EnterpriseFlifoFormatter-EnterpriseFlifoFormatter USER [BW-User] - Interface Name : EFF: Process ID :674526636 Ending ODS query Process to create enterprise message^M
2019 Apr 23 14:01:44:882 GMT +0000 BW.EnterpriseFlifoFormatter-EnterpriseFlifoFormatter USER [BW-User] - Interface Name : EFF: Process ID :674526635 Send Message Process has finished at  :  1556028104882 for flight 1206 departing on 2019-04-24 from EWR to CLT of type Leg Level Message^M
2019 Apr 23 14:01:44:882 GMT +0000 BW.EnterpriseFlifoFormatter-EnterpriseFlifoFormatter USER [BW-User] - Interface Name : EFF: Process ID :674526635 Send Message Process has finished at  :  1556028104882 for flight 1206 departing on 2019-04-24 from EWR to CLT of type Flight Level Message^M
2019 Apr 23 14:01:44:882 GMT +0000 BW.EnterpriseFlifoFormatter-EnterpriseFlifoFormatter USER [BW-User] - Interface Name : EFF: Process ID :674526636 Send Message Process has begun at  :  1556028104882 for flight 1196 departing on 2019-04-24 from CUN to ORD of type Leg Level Message^M
2019 Apr 23 14:01:44:883 GMT +0000 BW.EnterpriseFlifoFormatter-EnterpriseFlifoFormatter USER [BW-User] - Interface Name : EFF: Process ID :674526636 Send Message Process has begun at  :  1556028104882 for flight 1196 departing on 2019-04-24 from CUN to ORD of type Flight Level Message^M
2019 Apr 23 14:01:44:882 GMT +0000 BW.EnterpriseFlifoFormatter-EnterpriseFlifoFormatter USER [BW-User] - Interface Name : EFF: Process ID :674526635 Main Process is ending for flight 1206 departing on 2019-04-24^M
2019 Apr 23 14:01:44:882 GMT +0000 BW.EnterpriseFlifoFormatter-EnterpriseFlifoFormatter USER [BW-User] - Interface Name : EFF: Process ID :674526636 Main Process is ending for flight 1206 departing on 2019-04-24^M
```

So the process id is not in sequence, how can we use logstash aggregate filter to co-relate and send all the messages belonging to same process id as a single event

Comment: Thanks to your question I discovered this plugin https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html
It should work for you !
I leave my answer below with an EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check this [plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elapsed.html) that tracks a pair of start/end events and uses their timestamps to calculate the elapsed time between them, so based on an id, like you need, it identifies a 'beginning' event and waits for its related 'ending' event. here is a simple [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020545/logstash-elapsed-filter) of using it.

It could be useful to tweak this plugin to do what you need since it already handles timeouts, wait for events based on a specific field etc.

But you also need to be aware of these points :

- Knowing when to stop, until when do you need to accumulate events ?
- Is it ok to accumulate, potentially, a lot events in memory ?
- When to timeout ?

If you're ingesting lot of data, Logstash doesn't seem to me to be well suited to that need. 
Think about aggregating events using another tool, may be an apache spark daily job that aggregates your events using elasticsearch as a backend ?

EDIT:
I quickly checked the plugin's [source](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-elapsed/blob/master/lib/logstash/filters/elapsed.rb), and what I am suggesting is basically something like adding all the information you need to the 'unified event'.

Let's say you need to get the content of 'my_field' from all your events.
you could update the 167th line:

```
return add_elapsed_info(event, elapsed, unique_id, start_event.get("@timestamp"), start_event.get("my_field"))
```

LAST EDIT:
This plugin should work for you
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html